# Trying to clone an HTML class using jquery but each method I use the clone copies an infinite number of times

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

first time, dev student at uPenn.  I'm cloning an HTML element successfully but I can't get it to clone the number of times of an array's index using .length.  Here is what I have so far that is giving me infinite clones, thanks for any help:

```
$(function() {
console.log( "jquery, ready!" );

var usTime = ["9am", "10am", "11am", "12pm", "1pm", "2pm", "3pm", "4pm", "5pm"];
var militaryTime = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17];

    for (var i = 0; i < usTime.length; i++){
    $("section").clone().appendTo("main");}

})
```

Comment: because you select all the sections.... next iteration... select all the sections and clone, next select all....

Comment: The fix is to give the section tag you are copying a unique ID. When you clone it, remove the ID and then append it to the main.

Comment: Or `$('section:first')`, or `$('section').eq(0)`, or whatever.  Different ways to approach it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every iteration you select all the section elements. So each loop you select the ones you just added. Select it once and clone that each time.

```
var section = $("section");
for (var i = 0; i < usTime.length; i++){
  section.clone().appendTo("main");
}
```

Comment: Thank you epascarello!!  that worked!  I feel like an idiot ha!  Appreciate the help.